# ¿Como llenar select con javascript php y jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

Quisiera que me ayudaran con la duda que tengo

```
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario de registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
    <script src="../js/llenar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
    <form action="php/regcap.php" method= "post" class = "form-registro">
        <h2> Crear capitanes</h2>
        <div class ="contenedor-input">
            <input type = "text" name = "cedula" placeholder = "Cedula" class = "input-100" required>
            <input type = "text" name = "nombre" placeholder = "Nombres" class = "input-48" required>
            <input type = "text" name = "apellido" placeholder = "Apellidos" class = "input-48" required>
            <input type = "text" name = "user" placeholder = "Usuario" class = "input-48" required>
            <input type = "text" name = "pwd" placeholder = "Contraseña" class = "input-48" required>
            <select name = "congregacion" class = "input-100" required>
                <option value = "escoga una congregacion">Escoga una congregación</option>
            </select>
            <input type = "submit" value = " Registrar capitan" class = "btn-enviar">
        </div>      
    </form>
</body>
```

y este es el javascript

```
import ("jquery-3-2-1.min.js");
window.onload = function(){
    alert("hola");
    $("#cmbCongregacion").onload(function(){
        $.post("php/llenar1.php",function(data){
            $("#cmbCongregacion").html(data);
            alert("hola otra vez!");
        });
    });
    alert($.post);
}
```

Según leí se debe importar el archivo del `jquery`, pero no se si esta bien o mal

La verdad no se si esta bien escrito estuve buscando y encontré algo parecido, pero la verdad no me carga el `select`, se puede hacer directamente en el código de la pagina pero quiero aprender hacerlo de esta manera, me parece que se ve más profesional.

Si alguien sabe de un buen manual para principiantes se lo agradeceria

Agrego el resultado de la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya le agregue el id pero aun no lo llena, es como si no tuviera en cuen el código, agregare lo que me muestra la consola

Comment: Ya la eliminé y aún no me carga se que el php está bien por qué ya lo probé poniendo directamente el código PHP y si me cargo los datos en el select

Comment: Y cómo lo  incluyo???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 3 errores

- Tu `select` no tiene `id="cmbCongregacion"`.
- La línea `$("#cmbCongregacion").onload(function(){` no es necesaria.
- No estas incluyendo `jQuery` correctamente.

### Solución:

llenar.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
  alert("hola!");
  $.post("php/llenar1.php", function(data) {
    $("#cmbCongregacion").html(data);
    alert("hola otra vez!");
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Formulario de registro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">

  <!-- AQUI incluimos jQuery -->
  <script src="../js/jquery-3-2-1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="../js/llenar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
  <form action="php/regcap.php" method="post" class="form-registro">
    <h2> Crear capitanes</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-input">
      <input type="text" name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula" class="input-100" required>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombres" class="input-48" required>
      <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellidos" class="input-48" required>
      <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" class="input-48" required>
      <input type="text" name="pwd" placeholder="Contraseña" class="input-48" required>

      <!-- AQUI agregamos el ID al select -->
      <select id="#cmbCongregacion" name="congregacion" class="input-100" required>
                <option value = "escoga una congregacion">Escoga una congregación</option>
            </select>
      <input type="submit" value=" Registrar capitan" class="btn-enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Lo probaré y te comento, por cierto habrá algún tutorial sobre jQuery que me puedas recomendar?

Comment: @FamiliaValenciaHdz, te diría que [esta es la mejor](https://learn.jquery.com/), pero esta en ingles.

Comment: Gracias, lo mirare. imaginate que si carga los datos, pero no me los esta mostrando te dejo una imagen.

Comment: Y cómo hago para mandarte eso???

Comment: Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:56
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 28 Dec 2017 19:29:19 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.30

Comment: Ya me di cuenta, no me esa enviando el otro campo de mi tabla, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: nuevamente gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Lo que no entiendo por que no me esta cargando los datos
<?php
 include("conex.php");
 $sql  = "SELECT cod_congregacion, nombre_congregacion FROM congregacion ORDER BY nombre_congregacion ASC";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $html.="<option value ='".$row['cod_congregacion']."'>".$row['nombre_congregacion_congregacion']."</option>";
 }
 echo $html;
 mysqli_free_result($result);
 mysqli_close($con);
?>

Comment: @FamiliaValenciaHdz, es `$row['nombre_congregacion']`, no `$row['nombre_congregacion_‌​congregacion']`.

Comment: Gracias no lo analize

Comment: Hola marcos me podrías ayudar con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/127902/70496 gracias