# Por que se genera este error?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

Estoy tratando pasar unos valores a php por medio de jquery, pero me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

llenar.js:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btn-enviar");
  btnEnviar.onclick = enviarForm;
  var cedula = document.getElementById("cedula");
  cedula.onblur = repetido;
  $.post("../php/llenar1.php", function(data) {
    $("#congregacion").html(data);
  });
}

function repetido() {
  var cedula = document.getElementById("cedula");
  var valor;
  valor = cedula.value;
  $.post("../php/repetido.php", {
    cedula: valor
  }, function(data) {
    if (data == valor) {
      alert("El usuario " + valor + " ya existe");
      cedula.value = "";
      cedula.focus = true;
    }
  });
}

function enviarForm() {
  var cedula = document.getElementById("cedula");
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
  var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido");
  var user = document.getElementById("user");
  var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd");
  var congregación = document.getElementById("congregacion");

  cedula.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digite su numero de cedula');
  });
  cedula.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });

  nombre.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });
  nombre.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digite su nombre');
  });

  apellido.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });
  apellido.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digite su apellido');
  });

  user.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });
  user.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digite su usuario');
  });

  pwd.addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });
  pwd.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('Por favor digite su contraseña');
  });

  congregación.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });
  congregación.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt) {
    if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
      this.setCustomValidity('Por favor escoga una congregación');
    }
  });
  if (cedula.value != "" && nombre.value != "" && apellido.value != "" && user.value != "" && pwd.value != "" && congregación.value != "") {
    $.post("../php/reg_cap.php", {
      cedula: cedula,
      nombre: nombre,
      apellido: apellido,
      congregacion: congregacion,
      user: user,
      pwd: pwd
    });
  }
}
```

```html
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Formulario de registro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
  <script src="../js/llenar.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
  <form method="post" class="form-registro">
    <h2> Crear capitanes</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-input">
      <input type="number" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula" class="input-100" required>
      <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombres" class="input-48" required>
      <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellidos" class="input-48" required>
      <input type="text" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" class="input-48" required>
      <input type="text" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Contraseña" class="input-48" required>
      <select name="congregacion" id="congregacion" class="input-100" required>
   </select>
      <input type="submit" value=" Registrar capitan" class="btn-enviar" id="btn-enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Este es el PHP

```
?php
include ("conex.php");
$cedula = $nombre = $apellido = $cmbCongregacion = $user = $pwd = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $cedula = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cedula']);
    $nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['apellido']);
    $congregacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cmbcongregacion']);
    $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pwd']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hermanos (cedula, nombre, apellido) VALUES ('$cedula', '$nombre', '$apellido')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hermano_congregacion (cod_congregacion, cedula, user, pwd) VALUES ('$congregacion', '$cedula', '$user', '$pwd')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    mysqli_close( $con);    
}   
?>
```

los datos no se registran en la base de datos, es mas se demora mucho tiempo haciendo el proceso y después me bota el error que se puede ver en la imagen.

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: El error hace referencia a que tienes un bucle por ahí suelto que se come la memoria en JavaScript.

Comment: Lo único que tengo es nada función que se ejecuta cuando el campo cédula pierde el foco, será posible que eso sea el error?

Comment: Prueba de poner los scripts al final del body en vez del header.

Comment: También para optimizar, usa [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)  en vez de `window.onload`,  a no ser que tu código incluya el manejo de otras ventanas y elementos de las hojas de estilo.

Comment: @dddenis me sigue saliendo el mismo error. no se que sera, por que cuando ejecuto la funcion del campo cedula me funciona pero ahora que ya voy a guardar en bd no me deja.

Comment: lo utilizo para llenar el select, y para verificar que la cedula que se ingrese no este repetida y por ultimo para validar que todos los campos esten llenos y enviar la info al script de php para que me lo guarde en la bd

Comment: ya ejecute la funcion por la consola, persiste el error

Comment: precisamente el JS que subi es el archivo llenar.js

Comment: No logro reproducir tu error, definitivamente creo que debes ordenar tu código. Intenta borrar todos los addEventListeners de invalid y input que tienes en enviarForm

Comment: @UselesssCat el input es tipo submit no se si eso tenga algo que ver, quite el evento onblur a ver si eso esa el problema pero nada sigue el mismo problema

Comment: ya los comente y sigue el mismo problema

Comment: Le toca depurar el `JS`, comente toda la `function` `enviarForm()` y mire si sigue apareciendo...

Comment: @Michael,  Si sigue apareciendo, es más en la función repetido no sucede y cuando comento la parte del si donde envío todos los datos al php deja de suceder, solo sucede cuando entra a enviar los datos no se si tengo algo mal escrito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error se presento por que no le asigne ningún valor a las variables que reciben los objetos del html